# Module is not availabe in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="intervieweeApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Interviewee Evaluation</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.config.js"></script>

    <script src="home-view/home-view.component.js"></script>
    <script src="home-view/home-view.module.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>does it work?</p>
    <a href="#!home">go to home!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var intervieweeApp = angular.module('intervieweeApp', []);
```

app.module.js

```
var intervieweeApp = angular.module('intervieweeApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngMessages',
    'homeView'
]);
```

app.config.js

```
angular.
  module('intervieweeApp').
  config(['$routeProvider',
    function config($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
          template: '<home-view></home-view>'
        }).
        otherwise('/home');
    }
  ]);
```

home-view/home-view.module.js

```
angular.module('homeView', []);
```

home-view/home-view.component.js

```
angular.
    module('homeView').
    component('homeView', {
        templateUrl: 'home-view/home-view.template.html',
        controller: ['$http',
            function PhoneListController($http) {
                console.log(15);
            }
        ]
    });
```

home-view/home-view.template.html

```
 <p> at home </p>
```

error

> Module 'homeView' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
> https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/nomod?p0=homeView

When I load index.html, I get this error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You need to import the module registration before the other stuff. In other words `<script src="home-view/home-view.module.js"></script>` before `<script src="home-view/home-view.component.js"></script>`

Comment: Also, as a side note, `angular.module("name", [])` is a module registration (the thing used to initialise the module), where the dependencies are specified in the `[]` bit. I've noticed you're doing that twice for `intervieweeApp`; should probably only keep 1 of those.

Comment: As a caution, `bootstrap.js` doesn't play well with AngularJS.

Comment: @Protozoid Thanks. That fixed the problem. But when I go to 'home', The page does not change and the console.log function is not executed

Comment: @Thunfische : Did you look at my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the working DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/1nhanEkeXkXHOaitSM9W?p=preview)

You had issues because of sequence of js file import with `script` tag

The best practice when creating a module is to use [IIFE](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-stop-feeling-iffy-about-using-an-iife-7b0292aba174). This helps you not to think about the sequence in which you are importing `js` files in index.html

**app.module.ts**

```
(function(){
  angular.module('intervieweeApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'homeView'
  ]);
})()
```

**home-view.module.ts**

```
(function(){
  angular.module('homeView', []);
})()
```

The same IIFE concept is used in most of the open-source js plugins, so its a standard practice

Comment: Oh I missed to add ng-view to the index html. Thanks!